# access resolvers' grandparent params in graphQL middleware

Tags: graphql, middleware, prisma

I'm performing this query

```
query MyQuery($roomId: String, $closetId: String, $caseId: String) {
  room(roomId: $roomId) {
    closet(closetId: $closetId){
      case(caseId: $caseId)
    }
  }
}
```

I have a middleware applied to **case** where i need to perform a test on the first parent's arg **roomId**

I'm using the library https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-middleware

```
export const globalMiddleware = async (resolve, root, args, context, info) => {
  console.log(args.caseId)
  console.log(root.closetId)
  console.log(grandparent.roomId) // !!!!!!!!!!!!
  
  // ... do something
  return await resolve(root, args, context, info)
}
```

I can access its own arg caseId with args.caseId

I can access its direct parent's arg closetId with root.closetId

**Question** :
How do I access its first parent's arg roomId ??

PS: the code is ultra simplified, in my real code i have many more resolvers, nested on deeper levels. Which means that passing manually the argument roomId to every reslver is not a practical solution

I could go with accessing only the first parent's args though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the way it's build, there is no direct way to access resolver's grand-parent/first-parent.

One way to solve this is by passing all the query's params to the context:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: schemaWithMiddleware,
  context: async ({ req }) => {
    return {
      variables: req.body.variables
    }
  }
})
```

this way you can access all of the params in all resolvers:

```
export const globalMiddleware = async (resolve, root, args, context, info) => {
  console.log(context.variables.roomId)
  // ... do something
  return await resolve(root, args, context, info)
}
```